# How to update a textview while typing in an edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have multiple `edittext`and  a `textview` in the bottom in order to get the sum of what is written in the `edittexts`but I didn't succeded. I tried the `TextWatcher`but it doesn't do the work, for exemple i write in the first one 5 and in the second 10 I got 16 as a result as it counts 5+1+10. I also tried the `onfocus` method but the problem still with the last `edittext` it doesn't update the result. I really don't know what to do. Someone had this issue before?
TextWatcher implementation:

```
TextWatcher inputTextWatcher1 = new TextWatcher() {
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                sum+=number;
                tv.setText("sum is "+sum);

}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

        };
```

Comment: Can you post your TextWatcher implementation here?

Comment: Check my answer. I have tested it and working like a charm.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code. I have tested it and working like charm..

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            ans -= number;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        ans += number;
        txtOutput.setText("sum is " + ans);
    }
});

et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            ans -= number;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        ans += number;
        txtOutput.setText("sum is " + ans);
    }
});
```

Here, `ans` must be `0` before use. `et1` and `et2` are `EditText`.

**Logic**

`beforeTextChanged` will call before any text changes applied. Like you type **5**, then it returns **""** as there is no data, then if you type **2**, it returns **5** as it was entered earlier. So this is the trick.

Before adding any value, just subtract it from previous one. Otherwise your logic is true. but every time you are adding number in answer. Which make your answer false.

**Benefit**

Now, if you use this logic, there doesn't matter how many `EditText` there. This will provide true answer. You just need to add `TextWatcher` to every EditText.

Comment: @ChintanRathod, +1 from me. Good one. :)

Comment: Negative voters. Please add comment so that i can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say - editText1 - firstNumber & editText2- secondNumber

```
    TextWatcher inputTextWatcher1 = new TextWatcher() {
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                number1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
                number2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
                sum = number1 + number2;
                tv.setText("sum is "+sum);

     }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

        };
```